# async_receive_from вызывает повреждение кучи

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013

Идея такая: есть нить, которая поочередно проверяет пришло ли что-то в сокеты (`vecSock`) от определенного адреса (`vecEndpoint`), записывает пришедшее в буфферы(`vecBuf`), другая нить обрабатывает эти буфферы. Буфферы реализованы на основе `boost::circular_buffer` с мьютексами при модификации содержимого.
В результате выяснил, что проблема в `vecSock[i]->async_receive_from`, так как если эту строчку заменить на `vecSock[i]->receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(data_.data, 8000), vecEndpoint[i]);` с последующей аналогичной (как лямбда-функция у `async_receive_from`) обработкой данных, все работает отлично, не считая того, что это не то, что требуется.

Предполагаю, что проблема в `io_service`.

```
//объявления в членах класса:
typedef std::shared_ptr<udp::socket> SHP_Socket;

boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
vector<SHP_Socket> vecSock;
vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>> receive_threads;
vector<udp::endpoint> vecEndpoint;
vector<CThreadedCircular> vecBuf;

bool process_all_finishing=false;
//реализация методов:
void CRTPReceive::Run()
{
    io_service_.run();
}
void CRTPReceive::reinit_sockets(bool mode)
{
    int size = net_.my_ports.size();
    vecSock.resize(size);
    vecEndpoint.resize(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        vecSock[i].reset(new udp::socket(io_service_, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), net_.my_ports[i])));
    }
}

int CRTPReceive::process_all()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread1(new boost::thread(&CRTPReceive::receive, this));
    receive_threads.push_back(thread1);
    std::thread a(&CRTPReceive::Run, this);
    return 0;
}

void CRTPReceive::receive()
{
    while (process_all_finishing == false)
    {
        try
        {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < vecSock.size(); ++i)
            {
                Data data_;
                vecSock[i]->async_receive_from( boost::asio::buffer(data_.data, 8000), vecEndpoint[i],//
                    [this, data_, i](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t szPack)
                {
                    if (szPack > 12)
                    {
                        char DATA[szPack-12];
                        memcpy(DATA, data_.data + 12, szPack - 12);
                        vecBuf[i].push(DATA);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            cout<<"\nExeption";
        }
    }

}
```

Вылезающие ошибки:

> First-chance exception at 0x771FF70B (ntdll.dll) in server.exe:
>   0xC0000374: Куча была повреждена (parameters: 0x77234270). Unhandled
>   exception at 0x771FF70B (ntdll.dll) in server.exe: 0xC0000374:
>   Куча была повреждена (parameters: 0x77234270).
>
> First-chance exception at 0x7715E546 (ntdll.dll) in server.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xE768E351.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x7715E546 (ntdll.dll) in server.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xE768E351.
>
> First-chance exception at 0x608A70D1 (msvcr120.dll) in server.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFF32.

**UPDATE1:** из ответа Pavel Parshin получил такой результат:
1) Добавил буффер приема в свойства класса, так что его жизненный цикл соизмерим с классом.
2) убрал все лишнее для проверки из метода receive:

```
void CRTPReceive::receive()
{
    while (process_all_finishing == false)
    {
        try
        {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < vecSock.size(); ++i)
            {
                vecSock[i]->async_receive_from( boost::asio::buffer(vecData[i].data, 8000), vecEndpoint[i],//
                    [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t szPack)
                {
                    cout << "\nw";
                    if (szPack > 12)
                    {
                        cout << "\nqqqqq";
                    }
                });

            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            ;
        }
    }

}
```

На экран ничего не выводится. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [документации](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_receive_from/overload1.html) к `async_receive_from`:

> Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of
>   the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must
>   guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called.

То есть за жизненный цикл буфера отвечает пользователь, и буффер должен быть валиден до тех пор, пока не отработает `handler`.

В вашем же случае переменная `data_` удаляется после вызова `async_receive_from`, поскольку лямбда-функция не расширяет жизненный цикл захватываемых переменных + вы захватываете по значению (то есть копированием), что тоже логически неверно. Думаю, отсюда и проблемы с памятью.

По поводу того, что не происходит логирования: думаю, проблема в `io_service_.run();` - по сути это блокирующая функция, которая запускает `event loop` и обрабатывает все запросы. В вашем же случае эта функция завершается мгновенно и обработчики не выполняются. Попробуйте так:

```
    try {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < vecSock.size(); ++i) {
            vecSock[i]->async_receive_from(...);
        }
        Run();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        loggit("Exeption: " + boost::to_string(e.what()),0);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, сделал буффер в свойствах класса. Точнее, вектор из буфферов(пока пусть так). Но теперь какая-то другая проблема. Не выполняется лямбда функция. Сейчас в шапку вопроса добавлю обновление

Comment: @Dmitry, обновил ответ

Comment: И теперь очень странно: я отправляю по 172 байта, а принимается 2048... Почему так? При этом, сообщение ровно то, которое я отправляю, но переменная `szPack` принимает значение 2048, что крайне не удобно.
 Кстати, отладочная печать с cout работает в лямбда-функции